# Unable to setup Command + Shift shortcut on Mavericks

Tags: keyboard, macos, macbook-pro

I want to change Input Sources shortcuts

- **Shift + Option** - Select the previous input source
- **Shift + Control** - Select next source in input menu

[image]

This one is not working for me http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=646280 but if i put **Shift + Option + (any not_action key)** or **Shift + Control + (any not_action key)** than it works, but it is not what i need.

[image]

I read that mac not allowed only action keys as shortcuts, but I believe that somehow it could be done. Is there anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to for example map option-shift to option-F19 and control-shift to control-F19:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_R, ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_R, ModifierFlag::OPTION_R, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::SHIFT_R, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SHIFT_R, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then change the shortcuts for switching input sources to option-F19 and control-F19.